# opening a file with a popup message using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I insert a popup message inside a file using Python so that when my girl opens it she'll get these sayings "Will you marry me?"

Answer (score 0):

With tkinter you can do that. For example:

```
from tkinter import messagebox as MessageBox

titleWindow = 'Example0'
ask = 'Will you marry me?'
MessageBox.askquestion(titleWindow, ask)
```

With tkinter you can customize it much more, this is what comes by default